# How to browse files on your iPhone with Bash on Mac Book?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, terminal, bash

How to **browse files** on your **iPhone** with **Bash** inside the **Terminal** with iPhone connected to Mac with cable?

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Why? AFAIK there's really not a client for this; even iExplorer doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install Homebrew first, and then use this command:

```
brew install ifuse
```

to install the "ifuse" program from libimobiledevice.

It will allow you to mount and access the contents of the iPhone on your Mac.

Look at the guide [here](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse) for various options to ifuse that will allow you to mount various parts of the iPhone file systems (app containers, the media partition, the whole file system, etc.).

Comment: ```$ brew install ifuse```

```Error: ifuse has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!```

Comment: Solved after trying answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67155330/installing-ifuse-with-homebrew-results-in-error-message